# Algorithm for jugs?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

I am trying to come up with an algorithm that will work for the following situation:

1. Unlimited list of jugs
2. Each jug is given its maximum capacity.
3. The goal is to have a certain amount (x) is one of the jugs.

Here is an example:

```
Jug 1 = 10 capacity
Jug 2 = 4 Capacity
Jug 3 = 2 capacity
```

The goal is to have 8 in any of the jugs

I need to determine if its possible, if it is, I need to provide the sequence of moves that I used. Keeping in mind, I have have an unlimited under of jugs, and the "goal" is determined by the user.

Comment: Is this a question from a programming contest? I just wanted to ask so I can tag it as such. I will also remove the language tags, because your question is language-agnostic in nature

Comment: Also, you are failing to ask a question. It's always suspicious if there is no question mark in the question

Comment: Actually this sounds more like an assignment for an Algorithms class. Can you show us what you have tried?

Comment: Hi, its for a programming problem, not specifically for a contest. I am asking what the algorithm would be to solve the problem.

Comment: What is the source of the problem than? I find it hard to believe that this is not from a programming contest. It's not against the rules to ask about contest problems. Is it homework?

Comment: It depends what you are optimizing for. Minimum number of jugs? Making sure you contain all the liquid and have no space left in any used jug? Using the maximum number of jugs?

Comment: It is for a problem I was challenged to do. It is not for a contest. I am not optimizing it for anything, the goal is to have a broad algorithm that will accomplish the goal.

Comment: You can only have 8 in the jug that has room for 10. Shouldn't be that hard to write a loop to find that one?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen that is only an example; the algorithm is supposed to work for any set of jugs. (e.g. 50,45,,21,19,13,11,3.)

Comment: You can have 8 in most of those. To be clear, the question you've asked (?) is not all that clear. What do you mean by "have 8 in any of the jugs"? You mean pick a combination that sums to 8? Or pick any jug that has room for 8 or more? You also mention "sequence of moves". What do you mean by that? What are you moving? Again, the question is far from clear.

Comment: The goal is to have 8 in a jug. Doesn't mater which jug, but the goal is to have 8 (or any number given by the user)

Comment: And what do you mean by that? What does it mean "to have 8 in a jug"?

Comment: To have quantity 8 in a jug. For example, 8 liters.

Comment: Look, here's why I'm asking for this. I'm *assuming* that you mean this: I'm able to fill any jug with liquid. I don't have any other ways to measure liquids than the jugs I'm given. Since I can't measure the liquid without filling a jug with it, the question is how to use the jugs provided to get 8 liters of the liquid in a jug. For instance, given jugs with capacity for 10 liters, 4 liters, and 2 liters, I first fill the 10 jug, then I fill the 2 jug with liquid from the 10 jug, leaving 8 in the 10 jug. **However you have not specified this**. You're assuming people understand what you mean

Comment: To me it sounds like an easy loop through all of the jugs until you find one big enough, especially since he specifies `Each jug is given its maximum capacity.` I this isn't a homework question, I wonder if it's an interview question.

Comment: Does "Each jug is given its maximum capacity" mean, "the maximum capacity of each jug is given to us (i.e. we are made aware of it)" or, "we gave each jug enough liquid to fill it to its maximum capacity"?

Comment: The maximum capacity of each jug is given to us. We know what capacity it is able to hold.

Comment: Here is my very naive solution - http://ideone.com/gsxwgr - You can specify the jugs you have, how much liquid there is in each, and then it'll find every way to move liquid between them to get to the target goal. The goal is specified as a parameter to the HuntForGoal method. Basically the program recursively attempts every possible move and lists all steps that end up with the target amount of liquid in at least one jug. The program has one optimization in that it stores all the combinations it has seen to avoid endless loops.

Answer (score 1):

There's possibly something more efficient, but I'd go for some sort of [breadth-first search (BFS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search).

Start off with all jugs empty.

At each step, try to fill up each of the (non-full) jugs and try to transfer all the water in one of the non-empty jugs to another jug (until that jug is full or we're out of water) - each of these actions can be thought to be an edge between the current state (or node) to another state (or node) - this should make sense if you're familiar with BFS.

Continue until we get the target quantity in one of the jugs.

**Example:**

We have jugs of size 10, 4 and 2 and a desired quantity of 8.

So we start off with a queue of one element (as is typical with BFS) with all jugs empty:

```
{(0/10, 0/4, 0/2)}
```

Then we try to fill up each of the jugs, creating 3 elements in the queue:

```
    fill up 10         fill up 4         fill up 2
{(10/10, 0/4, 0/2), (0/10, 4/4, 0/2), (0/10, 0/4, 2/2)}
```

Then we take `(10/10, 0/4, 0/2)`, try to fill up 4 and 2, and try to transfer the water from 10 into the other jugs, creating the following elements:

```
    fill up 4          fill up 2      transfer 10 to 4  transfer 10 to 2
(10/10, 4/4, 0/2), (10/10, 0/4, 2/2), (6/10, 4/4, 0/2), (8/10, 0/4, 2/2)
```

Which are then added to the queue:

```
{(0/10, 4/4, 0/2), (0/10, 0/4, 2/2), (10/10, 4/4, 0/2), (10/10, 0/4, 2/2), (6/10, 4/4, 0/2), (8/10, 0/4, 2/2)}
```

And so on, until we get the required quantity in one of the jugs (which we actually already have with `(8/10, 0/4, 2/2)`).

Comment: Seems like this will explode with the number of jugs, but well, OP didn't specify any input restrictions

Comment: What if the first jug (they can be in any order) was filled to capacity? Would that change the algorithm much?

Comment: @user3220348 The starting state will only change the element you start with in the queue - so you'll start with `(10/10, 0/4, 0/2)` instead of `(0/10, 0/4, 0/2)`. If you start with all the liquid you have in the jugs, rather than having some unlimited source of liquid, you'll skip the "try to fill up each of the (non-full) jugs" step, as this is assumed to take water from that source, and then it should work perfectly.

Comment: @user3220348: Please restate your question in an understandable form with all the information included, especially what the start state is, how many jugs you can have and what moves you are allowed to perform. Otherwise you are just wasting everyones' time